# What collection do I use to input each line into streamreader?

Tags: c#, foreach, webrequest, streamreader, httpwebresponse

I'm having hard time figuring out what collection should I use, either the array `Numbers` or each line of text in my `WebResponce`.

Basically, the link in `Create` method returns 5 numbers. I want to take each line item and place it into array.

I'm having hard time wrapping my head around `foreach` loop needed to make this work, at least I think I should be using `foreach`.

```
        int[] Numbers = new int[5];

        WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(
            "http://www.random.org/integers/?num=5&min=1&max=56&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new");

        WebResponse myResponce = (WebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream myStream = myResponce.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myStream);

        Numbers[0] = Convert.ToInt32(myReader.ReadToEnd());

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {

        }



        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a collection.

Instead, you can read straight out of the StreamReader:

```
string line;
while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()) {
    int x = int.Parse(line);
    ...
}
```

Comment: So use while instead of foreach?

Comment: @DennisZaitsev, yes, but if you want the results in a collection you can say `numbers.Add(int.Parse(line))` in the loop, where `numbers` is `List<int>`.